# Can I use an aggregation function on the result of a previous aggregation function in Django?

Tags: django, python-2.7

I've been receiving the following error on a query:

```
Cannot compute Sum('failures'): 'failures' is an aggregate
```

I'm using django 1.11 and Python 2.7.

I have a model that represents a payment:

```
class Payment(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    customer_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=20) # e.g. 'paid' or 'failed'
```

When an user makes a purchase and tries to perform payment with her credit card, a Payment object is created. If the attempt fails, the status becomes 'failed'. An user may try several times, generating several Payment objects with the 'failed' status, and then give up, or maybe when she tried with a different card the nth payment was successful.

I would like to perform an aggregated query where I can count both the total number of failed attempts and the "unique" fails, that is, counting a single fail for each customer that had a failed attempt.

For example, suppose we had the following payment attempts

```
Date/Time          Customer Name    Status
2020-11-10 8:00a.m Alice            failed
2020-11-10 8:01a.m Alice            failed
2020-11-10 8:02a.m Alice            failed
2020-11-10 8:10a.m Bob              failed
2020-11-10 8:11a.m Bob              paid
2020-11-11 7:30a.m Charles          failed
2020-11-11 7:31a.m Charles          failed
```

I would like to obtain the following result using a queryset:

```
Date               Total failures   unique failures
2020-11-10         4                2
2020-11-11         2                1
```

On the first day there were 3 failures by Alice and 1 by bob, so there were 4 total failures, but if we don't consider repetitions there were only 2 unique failures. On the second day there were 2 failures, but a single unique failure.

So the first thing I did was aggregating by customer name, using a queryset like this:

```
qs = Payment.objects
    .annotate(date=TruncDate('created'))
    .values('date', 'customer_name')
    .annotate(
        # Sum payments only if status == 'failed'
        failures=Sum(
            Case(
                When(
                    status='failed',
                    then=1,
                ),
                default=0,
                output_field=IntegerField()
            )
        ),
        # I could not think of a better way of doing this... Basically
        # for every payment that has status 'failed' I return the value
        # '1' and then calculate the average, which should be '1', for 
        # whatever number of failures.
        unique_failures=Avg(
            Case(
                When(
                    status='failed',
                    then=1,
                ),
                default=0,
                output_field=IntegerField()
            )
        )
    )
```

This queryset works well and returns:

```
Date               Customer name    failures         unique failures
2020-11-10         Alice            3                1.0
2020-11-10         Bob              1                1.0
2020-11-11         Charles          2                1.0
```

Now I want to aggregate the values again, in order to obtain the total number of failures and unique failures per day, so I tried to do this:

```
qs.values('date', 'failures', 'unique_failures')
    .annotate(
        total_failures=Sum('failures'),
        total_unique_failures=Sum('unique_failures'),
    )
```

However this fails with the error:

```
Cannot compute Sum('failures'): 'failures' is an aggregate
```

Is there a way of performing aggregation functions on the result of previous aggregation functions? If not, would there be another way of counting the number of unique failures for each day? In other words, the number of customers that had at least one failure?